# Alarm with Text Reminder in C#

Tags: c#, reminders

I'm working with an `alarm` app using `C#`.

Firstly, I have a Form named `AddReminder.cs` which take Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min and some description about what to do in that time. If I click a button named `Add Reminder` then it all information will save in database/pc. It will be able to add many reminder as I want.

Then I have another form named `MyReminder.cs` which will match the times from database/pc and give me message and a alarm. I want to say, while the pc time will be exactly the saved or reminder time then this form will be executed.

Now My questions are:

1. How can I save multiple reminder in database or pc?
2. How `MyReminder.cs` will compare with those datas and execute with alarm?

I'm working in Windows and using VS2012. And over sure it's not the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270432/reminder-calender-c-sharp?rq=1).

This is AddReminder Design [Form](http://picpaste.com/addtodo-ZQGy0MX6.PNG). And the [Code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12499344/)

Comment: Code added #LegionMammal978.

Comment: What goes after `T_now.Text = `? Your code isn't very well documented... Also, what are `DAY` and `MONTH` set to?

Comment: Speaking of that, neither actually corresponds to the user's input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way to get the date from user is a control called dateTimePicker you can use it to get the input from user and very easily save it as a datetime variable
also the database supports the datatime variable type so u can easily insert it with an sql insert query

about how to know it's the alarm time ...there is a type of variable called timespan it can get the of subtraction  or the diffrence bettwen 2 dates ...use this type with an if statment ... if timespan = 0 then it's time

i know i didn't explan well but if u didn't get it i can show u some code

Comment: Have you implement before? If you implement please give me some direction. It's imergency.

Comment: drag a dateTimePicker control from the control box and put it in your form
you can store the date that the user select from the datetimepicker in a DateTime variable like that 
DateTime user = dateTimePicker.Value;
create a timer with interval 1000 and in the timer tick eventhanlder declare a datatime variable which will represent the time now .. u can do it like this 
DataTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
and you put it in a timer so the time is updated every second 
now we have two DateTime variables (the user selected time and time now ) you can substract them like that 
TimeSpan=user-timenow;

Comment: after that create an if statment 
if (user==timenow)
{MessageBox.Show("Time up");}
and for the count down you should also put the next line in the timer tick event
label1.Text = diffrence.ToString();
//diffrence is the time span variable name forgot to write it up there sorry 
hope that's helped